# Interacting with objects in SteamVR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

I'm trying to get Interaction setup in my scene for a colour memory puzzle game in Unity.

I've managed to get the scene changing when the player interacts with a button on a Canvas, so I'm trying to somehow replicate that through a puzzle.
The player can trigger the colour randomizer to display random colours (out of 4), then the player will need to 'press' the buttons on the panel in the correct order to proceed.

So far, I have a canvas overlapping the buttons so the player can interact with them. Each button has a box collider over the button element, so when the mouse is clicked or the trigger button is pressed on the Oculus controller, it should register a button press. But as soon as the hand comes into contact with the 'collider box' the following NullReferenceException Shows;

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Valve.VR.SteamVR_Action_Boolean_Source.UpdateValue()
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to reference each 'box' in code to that it knows its that specific colour being pressed. The code is there to accept keyboard input, just having trouble with the VR element.

Comment: Which language and engine are you writing your game in?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Using Unity C#

Comment: I'm assuming Unity3D?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Unity3D.